# Newbie problems with Node, Mongo, and Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to learn how to use Node, Mongoose, and Mongo by looking at code from GitHub.

What's the purpose of this line:

```
PostProvider = function(){};
```

from: https://github.com/cmarin/MongoDB-Node-Express-Blog/blob/master/postprovider.js

To me, it seems like an empty function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simulate the "class-concept" in javascript, we have [3 ways](http://goo.gl/VfBAW). One of this way is to use the prototype feature. Example for a Apple class :

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
}

Apple.prototype.getInfo = function() {
    return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
};
```

In your example, the PostProvider function has no attributes. So, "cmarin" declares an empty function :

```
PostProvider = function() {};
```

And add some methods :

- PostProvider.prototype.findAll
- PostProvider.prototype.findById
- etc.